# OptaPlanner 7.21.0 can't be executed from a jar file - a directory dataDir error

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to create my executable jar as I have completed my application and want to export it to other machines. I am however getting the error indicated. Any suggestions?

I have tried Jar with dependencies and shade as per the POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering</groupId>
    <artifactId>NurseRostering</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Staff Rostering</name>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.10</version>
        </dependency> <!-- Internal dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-common</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- Most examples use the XStream integration -->
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-xstream</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- TODO add examples that use the JAXB integration -->
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency><!-- TODO add examples that use the jackson integration -->
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-persistence-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-benchmark</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
            <artifactId>optaplanner-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>7.21.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- External dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Common utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Examples only dependencies. -->
        <!-- WARNING: every examples only dependency must be properly dealt with 
            in optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/assembly-optaplanner.xml -->
        <!-- Converters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>13-ea+9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-octicons-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-fontelico-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-ionicons-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-ionicons4-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-entypo-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-themify-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-materialdesign-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-foundation-pack</artifactId>
            <version>11.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp</mainClass>

                                    <!-- -Dlog4j.configurationFile=../properties/idStrikeSolver-log4j.properties 
                                        -Duser.timezone="UTC" -->
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The directory dataDir (/home/rodney/Desktop/data/nurserostering) does not exist.
 Either the working directory should be set to the directory that contains the data directory (which is not the data directory itself), or the system property org.optaplanner.examples.dataDir should be set properly.
 The data directory is different in a git clone (optaplanner/optaplanner-examples/data) and in a release zip (examples/sources/data).
 In an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans), open the "Run configuration" to change "Working directory" (or add the system property in "VM options").
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.determineDataDir(CommonApp.java:52)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.createSolutionBusiness(CommonApp.java:127)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:117)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.common.app.CommonApp.init(CommonApp.java:113)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.app.NurseRosteringApp.main(NurseRosteringApp.java:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this question by copy pasting the question :)

> ... The directory dataDir (`/home/rodney/Desktop/data/nurserostering`) does
>   not exist. Either **the working directory should be set to the
>   directory that contains the `data` directory** (which is not the
>   `data` directory itself) or ... The data directory is different in a
>   git clone (`optaplanner/optaplanner-examples/data`) and in a release zip
>   (`examples/sources/data`). In an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans),
>   **open the "Run configuration" to change "Working directory"** ...

Comment: Stackoverflow, don't I get a badge for pulling of this trick?

Comment: You should get a DelegateKiller badge for answering questions which originates with 0 research and laziness :D

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey. I note the comments by Kris. I had tried multiple things including Jar with dependencies. I then ran into the problem of the Kie config researched this to find the shade requirement within the POM. There were only 2 articles relating to this within Optaplanner/ Drools. I was thrown by the application working from with Eclipse and as such could not get my head around the error when doing a Maven Install . I thought the idea of stackflow was to help Kris. BTW I tried configuring the Working Directory as stated with no success

Comment: No worries, Rod. I know you'll have tried/researched far more than was is visible on the surface. It's a chance thing - when a 100 smart users try to get it working, there's always one smart guy who tries all the wrong things - by chance. That being said, I couldn't resist passing up the opportunity to answer the question like that though - it made my day :)

Comment: Let's talk about the earlier pitfalls you encountered: **there is no shade requirement** (although there is fat jar limitation on drools that inspires some users to start shading...). Personally, I advise to avoid shading in all cases. If you download the zip, and call runExamples.sh/bat it just works - thanks to manifest.mf entries in optaplanner-examples.jar - no shading at all.

Comment: Thanks heap for your help Geoffrey. I looked closely at your example Jar and was able to achieve my outcome. All works a treat now. I did initially have some minor issues with my classpath looking for my hibernate.cfg file and the solver xml but all good now